# wxPython: populate grid from another class using flatenotebook

Tags: sqlite, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to save a text file from the first page of a flatNotebook, write them to an EXTERNALLY defined sqLite database and write the values to a grid on the second page of the flatNotebook. The values are saved to the text file and written to the database successfully but I cannot get the values to populate the grid at the same time. They values show up in the grid after I close the program and restart it. I am having a hard time understanding how to call the function onAddCue(). I have tried so many things that I'm just confusing myself at this point. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my entire code:

```
cue =[4,'NodeA',11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]

class InitialInputs(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    global cue  
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.db = db
        self.cur = self.db.con.cursor()

        self.saveBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Save Current Values")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSave, self.saveBtn)

        self.dirname = ""

    def onSave(self, event):
        global cue

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            itcontains = cue
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'w')
            filehandle.write(str(itcontains))
            filehandle.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

        row = cue[0] - 1
        InsertCell ="UPDATE CUES SET 'Send'=?,'RED'=?,'GREEN'=?,'BLUE'=?,'RGB_Alpha'=?,'HUE'=?,'SAT'=?,'BRightness'=?,'HSB_Alpha'=?,'Fade'=? WHERE DTIndex=%i" %row
        self.cur.execute(InsertCell, cue[1:])
        self.db.con.commit()

        GridPanel().grid.onAddCue() #This is the part that's not working

class Grid(gridlib.Grid):
    global cue
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.CreateGrid(20,10)

        for row in range(20):
            rowNum = row + 1
            self.SetRowLabelValue(row, "cue %s" %rowNum)

        self.db = db
        self.cur = self.db.con.cursor()
        meta = self.cur.execute("SELECT * from CUES")
        labels = []
        for i in meta.description:
            labels.append(i[0])
        labels = labels[1:]
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            self.SetColLabelValue(i, labels[i])

        all = self.cur.execute("SELECT * from CUES ORDER by DTindex")
        for row in all:
            row_num = row[0]
            cells = row[1:]
            for i in range(len(cells)):
                if cells[i] != None and cells[i] != "null":
                    self.SetCellValue(row_num, i, str(cells[i]))

        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, self.CellContentsChanged)

    def CellContentsChanged(self, event):
        x = event.GetCol()
        y = event.GetRow()
        val = self.GetCellValue(y,x)
        if val == "":
            val = "null"
        ColLabel = self.GetColLabelValue(x)
        InsertCell = "UPDATE CUES SET %s = ? WHERE DTindex = %d"%(ColLabel,y)
        self.cur.execute(InsertCell, [(val),]) 
        self.db.con.commit()
        self.SetCellValue(y, x, val)

class GridPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.db = db
        self.cur = self.db.con.cursor()

        grid = Grid(self, db)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(grid)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def onAddCue():
        global cue
        row = cue[0] - 1
        col=0
        while col < 10:
            for i in cue[1:]:
                grid.SetCellValue(row, col, str(i))
                col = col+1

class GetDatabase():
    def __init__(self, f):
        # check db file exists
        try:
            file = open(f)
            file.close()
        except IOError:
            # database doesn't exist - create file & populate it
            self.exists = 0
        else:
            # database already exists - need integrity check here
            self.exists = 1
        self.con = sqlite.connect(f)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"Stage Lighting", size=(800,600))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)

        page1 = InitialInputs(notebook, db)
        page2 = GridPanel(notebook, db)

        notebook.AddPage(page1, "Initial Inputs")
        notebook.AddPage(page2, "Grid")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    db = GetDatabase("data.db")

    app = wx.App()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)          
    Frame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the question is about python syntax errors!

onAddCue is a method belonging to the class GridPanel.  The class is instantiated in the variable page2.

So, you need to call the method something like this:

```
page2.OnAddCue()
```

Comment: Either it is my syntax or my placement of the function onAddCue(). Without changing where I call onAddCue(), I get the following errors when I change the syntax: GridPanel().grid.onAddCue() gives TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given). GridPanel(parent, db).grid.onAddCue() gives NameError: global name 'parent' is not defined. onAddCue() gives NameError: global name 'onAddCue' is not defined. GridPanel.grid.onAddCue() gives AttributeError: type object 'GridPanel' has no attribute 'grid'. The cue [] is proper: it writes to the database. Other suggestions @ravenspoint ?

Comment: In your original post you said that the call did not work when you ran the program.  Now you are saying that you are getting syntax errors?

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I'm not being clear (noob). The function onAddCue works when used in the same panel as the grid. I can't get it to work from a different panel. That's why I think it's my syntax. Thank you for your help @ravensport , I'm still learning.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: page2.onAddCue() results in: NameError: global name 'page2' is not defined. Any other ideas? @ravensport?

Comment: you need to make page2 global, so you can refer to it.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to be real dense here: how do I make page2 global? @ravensport

Comment: Same way you made cue global